# Programmatically detect if a Kubernetes node is a master/control plane

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How via command line can I detect if a Kubernetes node is a master/control plane or not? Is there an environment variable I can check?

Comment: Do you mean inside the node, which is part of the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes provides [labels and selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) which can be used to select the role assigned to a node.

To select controlplane nodes, use a selector to select that role:

```
# kubectl get nodes --selector 'node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane' 
NAME  STATUS  ROLES              AGE  VERSION
cp01  Ready   controlplane,etcd  90d  v1.26.1
cp02  Ready   controlplane,etcd  93d  v1.26.1
cp03  Ready   controlplane,etcd  93d  v1.26.1
```

To see a list of available labels, print out the configuration of the node in YAML format, and look at the `labels:` section:

```
# kubectl get nodes cp01 -o yaml
...
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
    node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane: "true"
    node-role.kubernetes.io/etcd: "true"
...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `kubectl get nodes -o wide` command to get a more detailed list of the nodes, containing the Roles column. There you can see that control-plane, master, etcd nodes have a special label.

Comment: I'm looking to programmatically detect from a given node though if it's role is control panel. That will just list all nodes.